# How to add / bind multiple form values to server side blazor method

Tags: beta, asp.net-core-3.0, blazor-server-side

I try to expand the [server side blazor todo app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/build-your-first-blazor-app?view=aspnetcore-3.0#build-a-todo-list).

I would like to

- add a responsible person to a todoitem
- add a todoitem after onkeyup inside the input field

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/surfmuggle/95726c2588796410cebcce79d88b26bb/revisions) contains my attempt [to expand the todo app](https://gist.github.com/surfmuggle/95726c2588796410cebcce79d88b26bb/revisions)

#### What works

Adding a list of people inside a select field

```
<select>
    @foreach (var person in people)
    { 
       <option value="person">@person</option>
    }
</select>
```

#### What does not work

Two things are not working

1. adding a person to a `todoItem` inside `AddTodo()`
2. adding a `todoItem` for the event `onKeyUp == Enter`

The method

```
private void AddTodo()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newTodo))
    {
        todos.Add(new TodoItem { Title = newTodo, Responsible = person});
        newTodo = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

#### Questions

1. How can multiple form values (input, select) be bound to a method?
2. Why is onkeyup not firing?

Source code of [my Todo.razor gist](https://gist.github.com/surfmuggle/95726c2588796410cebcce79d88b26bb/revisions)

[image: Blazor server side todo app]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause for `why is onkeyup not firing?` was a silly mistake; the event handler was attached to the wrong input. This seems to work

```
<input placeholder="Something todo" @bind="newTodo" @onkeyup="AddTodoOnEnter" />
```

To get a value from a selected option from a select-tag to your code you bind the variable `@newPerson` on the `select`-tag.

```
<select @bind="newPerson">
@foreach (var person in people)
{
    <option value="@person" >@person.name (@person.id)</option>
}
</select>
```

You can access it inside the @code section with

```
@code {
// named tuple list  
private  List<(int id, string name)> people = new List<(int id, string name)>() 
    { 
       (1, "Tom"), (2, "Luise"), (3,"Jane") 
    };

private void AddTodo()
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newTodo))
  {
     todos.Add(new TodoItem { Title = newTodo, Responsible = "who " + newPerson });
     newTodo = string.Empty;
  }
}
```

#### Screenshot of the html

[image: Blazor Todo app with select]

#### Current Code / Gist

I updated my gist - you [can see the old code next the revision 4 side by side here](https://gist.github.com/surfmuggle/95726c2588796410cebcce79d88b26bb/revisions)